# Linear maps and image sets

Tags: linear-algebra

This is an exercise from the lecture notes in my linear algebra course, which I am seeking to understand further:

Let S and T be linear maps such that $S:U\rightarrow V$, $T:V\rightarrow W$.

Then why is it that Im(TS) is contained in Im(T)??

I have looked up explanations which start with:

*)Every basis of Im(TS) is a linearly independent set in Im(T),

**)and then you are able to extend the basis of Im(TS) to that of Im(T)...

Intuitively from what I understand: S can map elements of U onto the whole space V or just a subset of V. Therefore the basis of Im(S) is as best a linearly independent set of the same dimension of V, say n, or some integer less than n. Therefore mapping Im(S) under T, Im(TS) would imply that again at best I have captured the whole space W, or a subset of W as I have mapped Im(S) and not all V necessarily.

I don’t understand why * is true ??

Comment: $(TS)x=Ty$ where $y=Sx$.

Comment: That is essentially composition of maps right? So $T \circ S$ is $U \rightarrow W$ and what's $im(T)$?

Comment: "IMAGE. If T : Rn → Rm is a linear transformation, then {T(~x) | ~x ∈ Rn} is called the image of T. If T(~x) = A~x, then the image of T is also called the image of A. We write im(A) or im(T)."

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, Sorry I don't quite get what you are getting at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of Im(T)$=\left\{w\in W:T(v)=w, \text{for some } v\in V\right\}$. Then Im(TS)=$\left\{w\in W:TS(u)=w, \text{for some } u\in U\right\}=\left\{w\in W:T(S(u))=w, \text{for some } v\in \text{Im(S)}\right\}$

Then clearly Im(TS)  $\subset$ Im(T) $\subset$W where Im(TS) and Im(T) are vector subspace of W.  Then for any basis in Im(TS), it is also a linearly independent set in Im(T). So you can extend it to be the basis of Im(T) and W,

Comment: Why does being a basis in Im(TS) imply it is a linearly independent set in Im(T)? Is this because to be a basis in Im(TS) the set of basis vectors is linearly independent and spans the subspace. Since these basis vectors are contained in Im(T) these vectors are a linearly independent set of Im(T) and any lin indep set can be extended to become a basis for the space it is in? @James Chiu

Comment: Yes, you should read the proof of the basis extension theorem. The idea is to let $B$ be the set of basis of $Im(TS)$, we can find a vector $v$ in $Im(T)$ but not in $Im(TS)$ so $v$ must be linearly independent to every vector in $B$. Otherwise, it is in the span(B) and in $Im(TS)$.  This generate a new set $B\cup\left\{v\right\}$ which span (call U) is larger than $Im(TS)$. If $U=Im(T)$, then done. If not, repeat the same process, find a vector in $Im(T)$ but not in $U$, then carry on. Since the rank of $T$ is finite, in the end, we can construct an independent set span $Im(T)$.